# How to preserve paragraph breaks when text copy from PDF and paste into Notepad?

Tags: windows, pdf, text-formatting, notepad

For example when I copy text from PDF which has paragraph breaks like this:

```
xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx x xxxx xx
xxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxxx x x xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxx
xxxx xxxxxx

xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx x xxxx xx
xxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxxx x x xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxx
xxxx xxxxxx
```

but when i copy text from PDF and paste into Notepad, Word 2007 etc. output comes without paragraph breaks.

Like this:

```
xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx x xxxx xx
xxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxxx x x xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxx
xxxx xxxxxx
xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx x xxxx xx
xxxx xxxx xxxxxxxxxxx x xxxxxxxx x x xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxx xxx
xxxx xxxxxx
```

How to preserve paragraph breaks when text copy from PDF and paste into Notepad?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no concept of paragraphs (and therefore paragraph breaks) in PDF files.

You may try to use some Word macro that would try to guess paragraphs based on line length (last line in a paragraph is usually shorter) than other lines.

But otherwise, unfortunately, you are out of luck.